# Unexpected response code for Spring RestTemplate.getForEntity() after redirect

Tags: java, spring, redirect, httprequest, resttemplate

RestTemplate created as follows:
      (HttpClientBuilder comes from *org.apache.http.impl.client*.*)

```
CloseableHttpClient chc = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableRedirectHandling().build();
ClientHttpRequestFactory noRedirectFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(chc)

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(noRedirectFactory);
```

Used as follows:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity( ${url} , String.class);
int responseCode = response.getStatusCodeValue();
```

Now 3 cases for ${url}, differences only in query parameters:

1. http://www.boxofficemojo.com/intl/ukraine/?yr=2017&wk=27
   Query params values are all ok, page exists, *responseCode == 200* (as expected)
2. http://www.boxofficemojo.com/intl/ukraine/?yr=99999999&wk=999999
   Query params values are wrong, **redirect**, *responseCode == 302* (as expected, thanks to *noRedirectFactory*)
3. http://www.boxofficemojo.com/intl/ukraine/?someRandomParam=99999999
   Query params are wrong, **redirect**, **responseCode == 200**. How is that **different from second case**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because sending the 3rd request is same as sending the request with no query param so you would get the unfiltered full view; which is I believe is a normal scenario.

The reason why you might be receiving the 302 in 2nd case id because of the implementation of the service itself and the validation for query params **yr** and **ek** might be failing. hence service just knows to redirect in such scenarios.

Comment: I'm  a bit confused because when open in browser both 2rd and 3rd looks like the same redirect.

Comment: I received 302 redirect for 2nd case and 200 for 3rd case from browser. It is behaving as expected. Would you mind telling what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Obtain the URL with the query params: current year and the most resent week for which data was published. It's all ok as it's easy to implement a loop which starts with curent week and decrement week each time after 302. Just wanted to know how 3rd is different from 2rd. Thanks for your response, now it's clear.